# How to send variable with window.open JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to send a variable to a new window, when using the `window.open` function. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>`enter code here`
<script>
function myFunction(){
    window.open('test4.php?id=5', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $id=5;
?>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP variable `$id=5` is what I'm trying to pass to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>`enter code here`
 <script>
 function myFunction(value){
// getting value you want to pass
 window.open('test4.php?id=' + value, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

}
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $id=6;
?>

//you can add php value in any html like that.
 <button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $id;?>)">Click Here</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As a final note:
Before asking questions like that you should go with tutorial on these topics.